# SwiftUI: Vertical Scrollview doesn’t scroll at all, when using ZStack

Tags: arrays, swiftui, foreach, scroll

I am iterating an array of simple structs, containing a name and a color.
For each element I am displaying a rectangle with the specified color and a machting text element.

All of this is inside a `ZStack`, so be able to se all the elements, I am offsetting the rectangles, depending on their index in the array.

The problem is, I am trying to create a vertical scrollView, but it wont scroll. I keeps snapping back to the top.

**This is my code:**

```
ScrollView{
    ZStack {
        
        ForEach(Array(bookTags.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, tag in
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 300)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                .foregroundColor(Color(hex: tag.color))
                .overlay {
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text(tag.name)
                                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                            
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                        
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 30)
                }
                .offset(y: index != 0 ? CGFloat(index) * 75: 0)
        } // foreach
        
        
    } // zstack

} // scroll
```

**UPDATE**

Since .offset does not
change the height of the container, I tried using `.padding(.top, index != 0 ? CGFloat(index) * 75 : 0)`

This seems to fix the scroll issue. But for some reason the last element becomes all weird and funny looking.
Like this:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

When I add this line:

`.padding(.top, index != 0 ? CGFloat(index) * 75 : 0)`

and remove:

```
.offset(y: index != 0 ? CGFloat(index) * 75: 0)
```

I also have to remove the framing of the rectangle, if I dont I get this weird behaviour:

[image]

Comment: How about using a List instead of a ScrollView?

Comment: I actually dont think a list will work. I need the elements to be overlapping, and a list doesnt allow that. I think

Comment: So how are the items overlapping in your screenshot?

Comment: In the code provided I use a rectangle(), but in my "real" code, I use a custom shape, create with path. This custom shape has curves and indents. The reason I use a rectangle() in the code, is to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use offset to change the position of a view, it has no impact on the size of the view, so it has no impact on the size of its container either. This means, your `ZStack` will only have a height of 300.

Instead of using `.offset`, you could add top padding to the rectangles instead:

```swift
    //.offset(y: index != 0 ? CGFloat(index) * 75: 0)
    .padding(.top, index != 0 ? CGFloat(index) * 75: 0)
```

**UPDATE**
Following your updates and answers, two more suggested changes:

1. Remove `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)` from the rectangles
2. Apply these changes to the `ScrollView` and `ZStack`:

```swift
    ScrollView {
       ZStack(alignment: .top) { // alignment added
            // content as before
       }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
```

Comment: Thanks, i actually tried this. And it does fix the scroll issue, but the last element becomes very "short". I have updated my post

Comment: It's just clipped by the screen bounds isn't it? Try applying ```.ignoresSafeArea()``` to the ```ScrollView``` (or maybe the ```ZStack```) instead of to the individual rectangles.

Comment: yeah thats also what I thought. Doesnt seem to fix it tho

Comment: My guess is that it's being caused by code you've not posted. Maybe check if you're setting ```.offset``` anywhere else, or if the ```ScrollView``` is followed by other content (inside the same containing parent).

Comment: I have provided all the code there is. I have made a small update to my post. You are welcome to try out my code.

Comment: Answer updated with two more suggested changes.

Comment: Yes, that did it. `alignment: .top` was the missing key